# Android Studio 2.0 - NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256WITHDSA Signature not available

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I'm running **Android Studio 2.0 Preview 3b** and trying to use *"Generate Signed APK..."* from the *Build* menu.

I get the following error *Messages* pane:

```
:wear:packageRelease FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':wear:packageRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
...
Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: SHA256WITHDSA Signature not available: try using a newer JVM to build your application.
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.java:224)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 70 more
Error:java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256WITHDSA Signature not available
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.DefaultJcaJceHelper.createSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createSignature(Unknown Source)
```

Android Studio is using **JRE 1.7.0_55-b13 x86_64**.

I see the ***try using a newer JVM to build your application.*** suggestion. Will it help to upgrade Java? Or how can I resolve this?

I haven't seen anywhere (e.g. http://tools.android.com/recent) that a Java upgrade is needed for Android Studio 2.0.

Comment: Are you able to package your application without the wear package?

Comment: Actually, yes! :) Not that I would want to skip the wear module in this scenario though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just got the exact same problem with Android Studio 2.0 (the stable release) with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0`.

Even though my IDE was running with JDK 1.8_u77, I still had the problem.

To fix it, go to **Project Structure** > SDK Location > make sure **JDK** location is **set to** a **(at least 1.8) recent JDK** ! (at the time of this post, the latest is 1.8_u77).

Comment: This did the trick for me. I had an old project I was trying open, build, and generate a signed APK for. Ultimately, I installed the latest JDK (1.8 update 77), set the SDK Location as suggested here and I was good to go.

Comment: Finally a proper solution. Thank you. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I **got around the problem by changing version of the *Android Plugin for Gradle*** from version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2` back to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0` in the project's `build.gradle`.

I had upgraded the plugin to be able to use *Instant Run*.

Also, [tskulbru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215400/tskulbru)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318509/android-studio-2-0-nosuchalgorithmexception-sha256withdsa-signature-not-avail#comment56412634_34318509) about skipping building of the wear module worked as well.

Other attempts to fix this that did **not** work:

- Separate installation of Android Studio 1.5.0 and 1.5.1 (stable channel)
- Upgrade to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3` (and later different versions up to beta6)
- Upgrade to JDK 8u74
- Upgrade to Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6

Answer (score 0):

The version of the JDK your system is using needs to be the same as the version Android Studio is using.  For example, if running java -version tells you that you're using version 1.7 then Android Studio needs to be set to 1.7. This isn't a problem of using a version below 1.8...I am using 1.7.